# Asset Management & Deferred Revenues does not work with MultiCompany ,MultiCurrency

Tags: odoo

**Impacted versions:** All version of Odoo

**

- Assumption->

**

- *Multi Company Setup, Company A with base currency INR.
- *Company B with base currency AED
- Secondary currency = USD with following rates
- USD to INR= 70
- USD to AED = 4

**

- Steps to reproduce issue->

**

- Your Adminstrator User's company preference is Company A(INR)
- Asset created under Company B for 12 USD.
- Next Depreciation date 24june 2019 of 1 USD
- Cron Job/Schduler ran on 24june from Adminstrator User's account
  automatically.

**

- Expected result:

**

- Journal entry currency amount= 1usd
- Base amount conversion to AED = 4AED

**

- Actual result:

**

- Journal entry currency amount= 1usd
- Base amount conversion computed with USD to INR i.e 70.

This happened because cron job ran through Adminstrator User

Adminstrator User's preference/login company was Company A and base currency was INR

Comment: That is a functional question and doesn't belong to StackOverflow but to [official Odoo Forum](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1) or when it's a bug to the [Odoo Github Issue Tracker](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues).

Comment: Ok thanks.I have posted the query on Odoo forum and Odoo github